# How to include other project as framework library?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, include

I have two xcode projects in different folders, project A - is iOS App, project B - is Cocoa Framework. I want to add second project to first project as a framework, how can I do this?

(How I implement this:

Build and run B project -> Move root directory of B project in A project -> check 'Copy files' and select all targets and click Add -> but in this step if I try run `#import <B/B.h>` or `#import "B.h"` I catch error about not found file `B.h` in project A)

Also, in this example project  B is OAuthConsumer.

**UPD:** As far as I understood I need to include framework which is located in *.xcodeproj file? If it's so - then I got it right.